# Access values inside an array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array which contains two arrays like this:

```
b = [[a,v,d], [r,t]]
```

This array is created through this process:

```
const b = [];
for (let i = 0; i < clientsArray.length; i += 1) {
  if (clientsArray[i] === currentClient) {
    b[i] = clients.getIn([clientsArray[i], 'portfolios']).toArray();
  }
}
```

and when i `console.log` this it shows me this:

```
[Array[3]] [Array[2]]
```

but i want to create an array that shows this: `[a,v,d]` and `[r,t]`

How to do this?

Comment: When i remove toArray() it's an immutable list. I must use toArray

Comment: *"I have an array which contains three arrays"* - No you don't, you have an array containing *two* arrays. Anyway, it doesn't seem right that you would assign `b[i]` conditionally, because if the `if` condition is false you would leave holes in the `b` array where nothing was assigned. Maybe you should use `b.push(...)`.

Comment: You are right, sorry :P

Comment: But how do i access the values of the arrays inside the b array. I want to create an array that contains the values of the arrays no the arrays themselves

Comment: But the desired output `[[a,v,d], [r,t]]` that you show *is* an array containing arrays, with the actual values in the inner arrays. It would help if you could update your question to show the format of the source data. What exactly does the `.getIn(...).toArray()` return? (If you `console.log(b[i])` immediately after assigning it, what do you see?)

Comment: if i assign console.log(b[i]) it shows me the correct answer but i want to create an array with this answer. I must access the values of the arrays inside b array.

Comment: Seems like the problem is just that you don't understand how the console displays nested arrays. Is there not a little arrow that you can click on that expands the array so you can see the elements in more detail? Other than the `console.log()`, don't you have other code that uses `b` after it is populated?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried toString() ? It wont display in the manner you want, i,e:-[a,v,d] and [r,t]  , but would display:-a,v,d,r,t

Answer (score 0):

You can print the array using JSON.stringify.

For Example:
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));